# What is the most drupally way to add a slide show (as a block? So I can reuse it in multiple places)

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to Drupal 7, and just getting started.

I'm looking to add this slide show on my site:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

The "Manual and Auto Advance
(hover to pause, click to advance)" one.

What is the best way to do this?  My understanding is that Drupal 7 already supports a lot of core jquery stuff.  So, in which drupal file would I add the code

```
$('#id_name').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:   300,
    timeout: 3000,
    next:   '#s3',
    pause:   1
});
```

If this plugin is not already supported, then in which drupal file would I add the jquery cycle declaration, and where would I install those files?

More importantly, I am asking these operating under the assumption that I should make this a block, so that I could conceivably show this slideshow in multiple places on my site.  Is that a good strategy, or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content you want to use is already in nodes then you could use Views and Views Slideshow (which uses the cylce plugin you linked to).

With views you can create a block which can be re-used wherever you want in the site.

Learning how to use Views is one of the best things a new user to Drupal can do, it'll provides a lot of nice tools in a point and click interface.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on general strategy!  OK, so I know this is probably super basic stuff, but can I ask what you mean by if it is "already in nodes?"  When I try to do any node configuration, I'm presented with content types like articles and page, but none of them look like images?  Should I be making a new custom content type, called slideshow, or something, to use Views to do this?

Comment: Yeah you should create a new content type for your slideshow and add an imagefield to it. You can then create a new piece of content for each image. A node is simply the technical term for a piece of content.

Comment: OK, thanks, creating a node then digging into how to use views properly is definitely the right and most drupally correct direction for what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a content type to hold your slideshow elements is exactly what I do - title, text, link, image, basically whatever elements you need and then use Views with a Views Slideshow display type.